# unix commands in Informatica command task - what am I missing?

Tags: unix, task, informatica

I tried a simple

```
if [ 1 == 1 ]; then echo "Hi"; fi >>/projects/ods/Chk.txt
```

included in the command task but it fails with error code 512....

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

An `if/fi` block cannot redirect output.

use

```
if [ 1 == 1 ]; then echo "Hi">>/projects/ods/Chk.txt; fi
```

As you indicate this is a simple test case, if you need output from a larger block of `if/the/else/fi` or other logic, you can wrap it all in a process group and redirect that output..

```
{
   if [ 1 == 1 ]; then 
     echo "Hi"
   else
     echo "nope" 
   fi 
} >>/projects/ods/Chk.txt
```

Also, it's likely that using `==` is a problem. Typically you'd use `1 -eq 1` or other constructs like `if true ; then`, or if you really want good math comparisons, use `if (( 1 == 1 )) ; then ...`, but older shells may or may not support the `(( ... ))` test.

IHTH

Comment: tried if [ 1 == 1 ]; then echo "Hi">>/projects/ods/Chk.txt; fi failing with error code 512.
even tried -eq instead of ==, still failing!

Comment: what is your test concerned with, evaluation via `==`, redirection to files (`>>`), or both? What happens with `if true ; then echo "Hi" >> file ; fi` ? I don't think shell will return a number as high as `512`. Did you check your informatica documentation? Good luck.

Comment: Is there any clue in the output or in an Informatica log? That is to say, try `ls -ld /projects/ /projects/ods/` and confirm the UserID that your Informatica job is running as has perms to access and write to all dirs. OR simplify the problem a little furhter and try writing to a file/dir that is guaranteed to be open for writing to all, i.e. `echo "Hi" > /tmp/myTest`. It's possible that the append mode (`>>`) is causing problems, so try this sample, noting that it is 'create' mode, (`>`). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Found this while searching for some my queries.
you should use create mode instead of append mode. >> does not work, same happened with me. try this , if u are still facing this and needed an answer. :)